# Why does tokeniser break down words that are present in vocab

Tags: python, python-3.x, huggingface-transformers, huggingface-tokenizers

In my understanding, what tokeniser does is that, given each word, the tokeniser will break down the word into sub-words only if the word is not present in the `tokeniser.get_vocab()` :

```py
def checkModel(model):
    tokenizer = AutoTokenizer.from_pretrained(model)

    allList = []
    for word in tokenizer.get_vocab():
        word = word.lower()

        tokens = tokenizer.tokenize(word)
        try:
            if word[0]!='#' and word[0]!='[' and tokens[0] != word:

                allList.append((word, tokens))
                print(word, tokens)
        except:
            continue 
    return allList

checkModel('bert-base-uncased')
# ideally should return an empty list
```

However, what I have observed is that some models on huggingface will break down words into smaller pieces even if the word is present in the vocab.

```py
checkModel('emilyalsentzer/Bio_ClinicalBERT')

output: 
welles ['well', '##es']
lexington ['le', '##xing', '##ton']
palestinian ['pale', '##st', '##inian']
...
elisabeth ['el', '##isa', '##beth']
alexander ['ale', '##xa', '##nder']
appalachian ['app', '##ala', '##chia', '##n']
mitchell ['mit', '##chel', '##l']
...
  
4630 # tokens in vocab got broken down, not supposed to happen
```

I have checked a few models of this behaviour, was wondering why is this happening?

Answer (score 2):

This is a really interesting question, and I am currently wondering whether it should be considered as a bug report on the Huggingface repo.

**EDIT:** I realized that it is possible to define model-specific `tokenization_config.json` files to overwrite the default behavior. One example is the [`bert-base-cased` repository](https://huggingface.co/bert-base-cased/blob/main/tokenizer_config.json), which has the following content for the tokenizer config:

```json
{
  "do_lower_case": false
}
```

Given that this functionality is available, I think the best option would be to contact the original author of the work and ask them to potentially consider this configuration (if appropriate for the general use case).

**Original Answer:**

As it turns out, the vocabulary word that you are checking for is `welles`, yet the vocab file itself only contains `Welles`. Notice the difference in the uppercased first letter?
It turns out you can manually force the tokenizer to specifically check for cased vocabulary words, in which case it works fine.

```py
from transformers import AutoTokenizer

tokenizer = AutoTokenizer.from_pretrained("emilyalsentzer/Bio_ClinicalBERT",
                                          do_lower_case=False)  # This is different
print(tokenizer.do_lower_case)
# Output: False

# Lowercase input will result in split word
tokenizer.convert_ids_to_tokens(tokenizer("welles")["input_ids"])
# Output: ['[CLS]', 'well', '##es', '[SEP]']

# Uppercase input will correctly *not split* the word
tokenizer2.convert_ids_to_tokens(tokenizer2("Welles")["input_ids"])
['[CLS]', 'Welles', '[SEP]']
```

Per default, however, this is not the case, and all words will be converted to lowercase, which is why you cannot find the word:

```py
from transformers import AutoTokenizer

tokenizer = AutoTokenizer.from_pretrained("emilyalsentzer/Bio_ClinicalBERT")

# Per default, lowercasing is enabled!
print(tokenizer.do_lower_case)

# Output: True

# This time now we get the same (lowercased) output both times!
tokenizer.convert_ids_to_tokens(tokenizer("welles")["input_ids"])
['[CLS]', 'well', '##es', '[SEP]']
tokenizer.convert_ids_to_tokens(tokenizer("Welles")["input_ids"])
['[CLS]', 'well', '##es', '[SEP]']
```

Comment: Yeah, `do_lower_case` does seems to mitigate this problem. However, this is still counter intuitive as the input word is in the exact case in the vocab, yet it is breaking them down. I am not sure if this is a tokenizer bug or the model's problem.

Comment: I don't see why exactly this is counter-intuitive? The vocabulary has an uppercased word, so obviously a lowercased version of the input will not be matched. If you want to alter the original vocabulary, you could of course also lowercase all vocabulary words of the original model, but this might cause some unwanted side effects.

Comment: if we look at the output above 
output: 
welles ['well', '##es']
lexington ['le', '##xing', '##ton']

These are the words in **lower case**, which are present in the vocab in the exact case, because all I did was iterating through the vocab. Yet the vocab is breaking them down.

It would have been reasonable if the output was:
output: 
Welles ['well', '##es']
Lexington ['le', '##xing', '##ton'].

Comment: Except that they are not present. If you check the [vocabulary of the linked model](https://huggingface.co/emilyalsentzer/Bio_ClinicalBERT/raw/main/vocab.txt) and Ctrl+F for `welles`, you will only find an upper-cased `Welles` as part of the vocab. What might cause some confusion is that you are calling `word = word.lower()` in your `checkModel()` function, so you turn everything into a lowercase word anyways...

Answer (score 2):

The tokenizer you are calling 'emilyalsentzer/Bio_ClinicalBERT' has tokens that are not present in the original base tokenizer. To add tokens to the tokenizer one can either provide a list of strings or a list of `tokenizers.AddedToken`s.

The default behavior in both cases is to allow new words to be used as subwords. In my example if we add 'director' and 'cto' to the tokenizer, then 'director' can be broken down into 'dire' + 'cto' + 'r' ('dire' and 'r' are a part of the original tokenizer). To avoid this, one should use:

```
tokenizer.add_tokens([tokenizers.AddedToken(new_word, single_word = True) for new_word in new_words])
```

I do think a lot of users would simply use a list of strings (as I did, until half an hour ago). But this would lead to the problem that you saw.

To change this for a customized tokenizer (like 'emilyalsentzer/Bio_ClinicalBERT') w/o losing much in model performance, I'd recommend extracting the set of words from this tokenizer, and comparing it to its base tokenizer (for example 'bert-base-uncased'). This will give you the set of words that were added to the base tokenizer as part of model re-training. Then take the base tokenizer and add this new words to it using AddedToken with single_word set to True. Replace the custom tokenizer with this new tokenizer.